# Maxima doesn't work in wxMaxima settings only command line on mac

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I just installed Maxima. I am trying to use wxMaxima. It doesn't seem to work. You can see here if I do 2*10; it doesn't seem to output it. It only works on the command line. I tried uninstalling and installing and it seems to be working on the command line only. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0lbY.jpg)

Comment: Well, wxMaxima doesn't send the input to Maxima until you press shift-enter (not just enter). If you are having installation problems, my advice is to open a bug report on the wxMaxima issue tracker. See: https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues

Comment: @RobertDodier I didn't know about the shift enter. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it worked for you.